# What's the difference between 2d vector and map of vector?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stdmap, 2d-vector

Let's say I've declared

```
map< int , vector<int> > g1;
vector< vector<int> > g2;
```

What are the similarities and dissimilarities between these two ?

Comment: map is an associative container while vector is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are fundamentally different. While you may be able to do both `g2[0]` and `g1[0]`, the behavior is vastly different. Assume there is nothing at index 0, then `std::map` will default construct a new value_type, in this case a vector, and return a reference, whereas `std::vector` has undefined behavior, but typically either segfaults or returns garbage.

They are also completely different in terms of memory layout. While `std::map` is backed by a red-black tree, `std::vector` is contiguous in memory. So inserting into the map will always result in dynamic allocation somewhere in memory, whereas the vector would be resized in case its current capacity is exceeded. Note however, that a vector of vectors is not contiguous in memory. The first vector, which itself is contiguous in memory is made up of vectors which look roughly like this in terms of data:

```
struct vector 
{
    T* data;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
};
```

Where each of the vectors owns its dynamic memory allocation at `data`.

The advantage of the map is that is does not have to be densely populated, i.e. you can have something at index 0 and 12902 without all the stuff in between, plus it is sorted. If you don't need the sorted property and can use c++11 consider `std::unordered_map`. The vector is always densely populated, i.e. at size 10000, elements 0-9999 exist.

Comment: Note that RB-tree is not specified by the standard. It's implementation-dependent, even if it's the case most of the time.

Comment: true, but do you know an implementation which does not use a rb-tree? IIRC the standard typically only demands certain asymptotic runtimes for certain operations, but in practice the memory allocation strategy has a much bigger impact that the asymptotic runtime difference in most cases.

Comment: No, but there is so many strange compilers, I would not be surprised if some of them implement other algorithms (like Casio or Texas Instrument, already using bytes of 16 bits, for example).

Comment: yeah, but that is not something the complier would do, this comes from the stdlib you use (libstdc++ (typically with gcc), libc++ (typically with clang), SGI). The byte-size of 16 bits afaik is totally different from that, since these things are typically imposed by the machine architecture (march).

Answer (score 1):

The similarity is the way you access data, it can be the same syntax:

```
std::cout << g1[3][2] << std::endl;
std::cout << g2[3][2] << std::endl;
```

The main difference is the following: the map of vector doesn't have to contain all the indices. Then, you can have, as example, only 3 vectors in your map accessed with keys '17', '1234' and `13579` :

```
g2[17].resize(10);
g2[1234].resize(5);
g2[13579].resize(100);
```

If you want the same syntax with a vector of vectors, you need to have at least 13579 vectors (including 13576 empty vector) in your main vector. But this will use a lot of unused space in the memory.

Moreover, in your map, you also can access your vectors with negative keys (which is not possible in the vector of vectors):

```
g2[-10].resize(10);
```

After this obviously high difference, the storage of data is different. The vector allocates contiguous memory, while the map is stored as tree. The complexity of access in the vector is `O(1)`, while it's `O(log(n))` in the map. I invite you to learn some tutorial about containers in C++ to understand all the differences and the usual way to use them.

Answer (score 0):

With example you can understand the difference. Lets say the `vector<int>` stores unique ids of people, and `map` stores respective pincode as key.

```
map< int , vector<int> > listOfPeopleAtRespectivePinCode;
vector< vector<int> > bunchOfGroupsOfPeople;
```

Evidently, `map` are capable to associate key and value (here a list of values), while `vector` can efficiently store a bunch of data.